# pyspark convert transactions into a list of list

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, sequence, reduce

I want to use PrefixSpan sequence mining in pyspark. The format of data that I need to have is the following:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c']],  [['a'], ['c', 'b'], ['a', 'b']],  [['a', 'b'], ['e']], [['f']]]
```

where the innermost elements are productIds, then there are orders (containing list of products) and then there are clients (containing lists of orders).

My data has transactional format:

```
clientId orderId product
```

where orderId has multiple rows for separate products and clientId has multiple rows for separate orders.

Sample data:

```
test = sc.parallelize([[u'1', u'100', u'a'],
 [u'1', u'100', u'a'],
 [u'1', u'101', u'b'],
 [u'2', u'102', u'c'],
 [u'3', u'103', u'b'],
 [u'3', u'103', u'c'],
 [u'4', u'104', u'a'],
 [u'4', u'105', u'b']]
)
```

My solution so far: 
1. Group products in orders:

```
order_prod = test.map(lambda x: [x[1],([x[2]])])
order_prod = order_prod.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a + b)
order_prod.collect()
```

which results in:

```
[(u'102', [u'c']),
 (u'103', [u'b', u'c']),
 (u'100', [u'a', u'a']),
 (u'104', [u'a']),
 (u'101', [u'b']),
 (u'105', [u'b'])]
```

2. Group orders in customers:

```
client_order = test.map(lambda x: [x[0],[(x[1])]])
df_co = sqlContext.createDataFrame(client_order)
df_co = df_co.distinct()
client_order = df_co.rdd.map(list)
client_order = client_order.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a + b)
client_order.collect()
```

which results in:

```
[(u'4', [u'105', u'104']),
 (u'3', [u'103']),
 (u'2', [u'102']),
 (u'1', [u'100', u'101'])]
```

Then I want to have a list like this:

```
[[[u'a', u'a'],[u'b']], [[u'c']], [[u'b', u'c']], [[u'a'],[u'b']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using PySpark dataframe (not that I use PySpark 2.1). First, you have to transform RDD to Dataframe.

```
df = test.toDF(['clientId', 'orderId', 'product'])
```

And this is the snippet to group the dataframe. Basic idea is to group by `clientId` and `orderId` first and aggregate `product` column together. Then group again by only `clientId`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df_group = df.groupby(['clientId', 'orderId']).agg(func.collect_list('product').alias('product_list'))
df_group_2 = df_group[['clientId', 'product_list']].\
    groupby('clientId').\
    agg(func.collect_list('product_list').alias('product_list_group')).\
    sort('clientId', ascending=True)
df_group_2.rdd.map(lambda x: x.product_list_group).collect() # collect output here
```

Result is the following:

```
[[['a', 'a'], ['b']], [['c']], [['b', 'c']], [['b'], ['a']]]
```